# Why can't I access a function inside async function

Tags: javascript, json, api

In the below program first I have accessed async function inside a function. And again I am trying to access another function inside a async function is it possible. Where have I gone wrong? (I completely used JavaScript dom)

```js
document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="container">
    <div class="search">
        <label for="search">Advanced Search</label>
        <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <div class="name">
        <label for="text">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="nameinput" placeholder="Click to get Data">
    </div>
    <div class="cardsdisplay" id="cardsdata"></div>
    </div>
    `

const namelabel = document.querySelector("#nameinput")
let cards = document.querySelector("#cardsdata")
namelabel.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const keypressed = event.key
  if (keypressed == "Enter") {
    //Acessing the getData function
    getData()
  }
})

const getData = async() => {
  //Fetch the data from api
  try {
    const data = await fetch("https://api.nationalize.io/?name=" + namelabel.value)
    const countries = await data.json();
    cards.innerHTML = "";
    alert("I am in")
    console.log(cards.innerHTML)
    countries.country.forEach((countrykey) => {
      alert("I am in")
      //accessing dispalyCountry function
      displayCountry(countrykey)
    })
  } catch (error) {}
  //Displaying the data
  let displayCountry = (obj) => {
    alert("I am infunction")
    cards.innerHTML += `
        <div class="main-container">
            <p>Name:<span>${countries.name}</span></p>
            <p>Name:<span>${obj.country_id}</span></p>
            <p>Name:<span>${obj.probability}</span></p>
        </div>
        `


  }

}
```

Comment: Change `let displayCountry = (obj) => {` to `function displayCountry(obj) {` or move it to the top of the enclosing function. You've run into a [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) problem.

Comment: What should I return function displayCountry(obj) to get the displayCountry cards inside cardsdisplay division and cards to display in the html dom

Comment: You've got another problem, `countries` that you use in `displayCountry` is not defined anywhere. To catch errors like that you need to report them in the `catch` block. Otherwise it will be hard for you to find what caused one or another problem.